# How to run Etherpad Lite on iisnode

Tags: iisnode, etherpad

How can I have Etherpad Lite running on IIS using iisnode?

*(updated 2013-04-23 after some more investigation)*

**My steps (first try)**

1. Install Etherpad Lite to `c:\eplite` and make sure it works when running with start.bat.
2. Install URL rewrite module for IIS (required for iisnode).
3. Install iisnode.
4. Grant IIS_IUSRS full control on the whole `c:\eplite` (an overkill, but to be sure there is no access problems).
5. Configure IIS web site pointing to `c:\eplite`.
6. Move `c:\eplite\node_modules\ep_etherpad-lite\Web.config` to `c:\eplite`.

Opening IE, I can see "something like" etherpad, but it doesn't work. On the main page there is no text (only field and buttons), trying to open the pad results in unworking pad interface with text:

```
An error occured while loading the pad
Invalid argument. in http://localhost/static/js/l10n.js (line 1)
```

**My steps (second try, after reading discussion [here](http://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/237))**

`7.` Edit settings.json: delete `port`.

`8.` Create c:\eplite\start_iisnode.bat:

```
cd c:\eplite
node "c:\Program Files\iisnode\interceptor.js" "c:\eplite\node_modules\ep_etherpad-lite\node\server.js"
```

`9.` Add the following line to Web.Config:

<iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="c:\eplite\start_iisnode.bat" />

Opening IE, this time I can see the correct start page.
Opening a pad results in unworking pad interface with text:

```
An error occured while loading the pad
The module at "ep_etherpad-lite/static/js/rjquery" does not exist. in http://localhost/static/js/require-kernel.js (line 1)
```

According to process monitor, it tries to find this module in the following path:

```
C:\eplite\node_modules\ep_etherpad-lite\static\pipe\fb92fd16-78e4-4f00-bac4-6a4935ebd0d4\static\plugins\ep_etherpad-lite\static\js\rjquery.js
```

**What else I have tried**

1. Steps 1-4 + configure IIS web site pointing to c:\eplite\node_modules\ep_etherpad-lite (Web.config location) + remove `node_modules\ep_etherpad-lite` path from everywhere in Web.Config. Result is the same as from original steps 1-6.
2. Steps 1-4,7-9 + configure IIS web site pointing to c:\eplite\node_modules\ep_etherpad-lite (Web.config location) + remove `node_modules\ep_etherpad-lite` path from everywhere in Web.Config. Result is the same as from original steps 1-9.

**Version info**

Etherpad Lite from "master" code branch (latest release was 1.2.10), built with installOnWindows.bat.

Node version 0.8.4 x64, iisnode version 0.2.4 x64.

Running on Windows 8.

Comment: did you ever get this to work - I am attempting the same thing at the moment?

Comment: No. The project I was trying this for is closed now, so I gave up.

Comment: for someone looking for answers, i have documented my recent experience on running Etherpad on Windows in general. [here on my blog](https://blog.kmonsoor.com/running-etherpad-on-windows)

Comment: @kmonsoor As I can see, you just ran it with start.bat, not IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work after reading replies of yours and others' in that [discussion](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/237) you mentioned, while it is not a perfect solution and there are some hard-coded options.

First six steps are the same as yours.

For step 7, DO NOT delete the port in settings.json as this will be used in next steps.

Step 8 and 9 are not necessary but you can change the content of web.config to this as shown in [@ghost's](https://github.com/ghost) post:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="iisnode" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="node_modules/ep_etherpad-lite/node/iisnode" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{{REQUEST_URI}}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{{REQUEST_FILENAME}}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

After that, make a symbol link from root path of etherpad(e.g. c:\eplite) to the actual server.js file(C:\eplite\node_modules\ep_etherpad-lite\node\server.js). This can be done by using **MKLINK**. In this example, you can type this in cmd:

```
mklink c:\eplite\server.js C:\eplite\node_modules\ep_etherpad-lite\node\server.js
```

"This resolves some of the weird pathing / module not found issues Node encounters otherwise." and then we need to add http-proxy module to etherpad-lite. Set current document in cmd to be C:\eplite\node_modules\ep_etherpad-lite and run **npm update & npm install http-proxy** and finally put these codes at the beginning of server.js:

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://localhost:9001'}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Note that the port in the target path should be same as the port in setting.json otherwise you cannot reach the etherpad site from the path binded in IIS.

I have tried to remove the hard-code or of the target path by replacing them with settings.port but this didn't work and there would an **error: npm.load() required** if I put it before the asyns.waterfall part. If i put the proxy creating code in any callback function inside asyns.waterfall, there will be an **Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL**. I was wondering if there is any other better solution for integrating IIS and etherpad. Thanks!.

My environment is Win7 + Node.Js 0.10 + IIS7 + iisnode v0.2.16 + etherpad Lite from develop branch (latest release was 1.4.10)

Comment: The project where I tried to run etherpad was closed long ago, so I cannot try your solution. May be, it will help someone other.